# SQL Server ARITHABORT setting

Tags: sql-server, arithabort

Where is the best place to set **ARITHABORT** ON? In Db or in App? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190306.aspx) says to turn on in logon session. If we have to turn on every logon session, why I cannot turn on in DB instead of turning on in every logon session.

Comment: Why do you want to set it on anyway? If `ANSI_WARNINGS’ is on then it effectively is on since 2005.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?